# What adjective would describe the idea of 'embeded in the core principles of'?

Tags: word-request

In this sentence for examle, 'Taking responsibility for one's own actions is ·embeded in the core principles of· this particular society.', what adjective would best substitute 'embeded in the core principles of'?

I could think of 'characteristic of', but it does not seem to convey the idea of an 'absolutely necessary requirement'.

Answer (score 1):

From [Oxford Dictionaries...](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inherent)

> **inherent** (adjective)
>    Existing in something as a permanent, essential, or characteristic attribute.
>    *any form of mountaineering has its inherent dangers*

Of course, there are alternatives - *The rights of the individual are **fundamental** to Western values,* for example. Or check out synonyms for ***innate, essential, intrinsic, built-in...***